# How to search for a combination of words inside a nested bullet list in regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to search for a combination of two words (let’s say term1 and term2) inside a bullet list. The condition is that these two words have to be from the same nested list and that the search has to be for any combination of these two words. Nested lists are separated by two new lines `\n`.

The input text

```
- Example nested list 1
    - This point contains term 2
    - This point contains term 1

- Example nested list 2
    - This line contains term 2
```

In order to achieve this I first tried to capture different nested lists in different capture groups.

`- ([\s\S]*?)\n\n`

Now, I would like to search inside each of these capture groups but I can’t seem to find out how.
An example regex is at https://regex101.com/r/OC6OI5/12

Edit:
For people who are wondering why this might be useful, I’m trying to build a Roam Research like Linked references filtering in a markdown editor

Comment: Is the maximum 1 nested list? And both words should be only in this single nested list?

Comment: What if both words appear in the same bullet point?

Comment: Both words have to be in the same nested list. The indents in the list is not defined. There could be multiple indents. Also, the terms can be on the first line of the nested list. The term doesn’t have to be on the indented bullet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there should be only a single nested list, and the term 1 and term 2 should be both present, you could use 2 lookahead assertions `(?=`

You could start the match at the start of the string, and match all lines that start with `-`.

Then you can assert what follows are lines that all begin with 1 or more whitespace chars without a newline followed by `-`.

Use 2 positive lookaheads to assert both terms, and match all following lines that have that same indentation.

```
^(?:-.*\r?\n)+(?=(?:[^\S\r\n]+-.*\r?\n)*[^\S\r\n]+.*(term 1))(?=(?:[^\S\r\n]+-.*\r?\n)*[^\S\r\n]+-.*(term 2))(?:[^\S\r\n]+.*(?:\r?\n|$))+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:-.*\r?\n)+` Match 1+ times a line that starts with `-`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:[^\S\r\n]+-.*\r?\n)*` Optionally repeat lines that start with whitespaces without newlines, then `-` and the rest of the line
  - `[^\S\r\n]+-.*(term 1)` Match a line that starts with 1+ whitespaces followed by `-` and contains `term 1`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?=(?:[^\S\r\n]+-.*\r?\n)*[^\S\r\n]+.*(term 2))` The same lookahead mechanism again for `term 2`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\S\r\n]+-.*(?:\r?\n|$)` Match a line that starts with 1+ whitespaces followed by `-` and the rest of the line
- `)+` Close the group and repeat 1+ more times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6w8Ek/1)

Comment: OP's question makes it sound like https://regex101.com/r/er4gmP/1 is possible but your regex is not catching list #2

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Thanks. Also one correction, I would like to capture term 1 and term 2 at any indentation. They are not necessarily on the same indentation.

Comment: @Sughanth Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/qNqBy4/1 `^(?:-.*\r?\n)+(?=(?:[^\S\r\n]+-.*\r?\n)*[^\S\r\n]+.*(term 1))(?=(?:[^\S\r\n]+.*\r?\n)*[^\S\r\n]+.*(term 2))(?:[^\S\r\n]+.*(?:\r?\n|$))+`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You are right, thanks! I have commented a different pattern without a fixed indent and updated the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you so much. My head hurts even trying to understand the logic of the regex. I can only imagine how hard it would have been thinking coming up with something like this.

Comment: @Thefourthbird How can I ensure that the regex also catches the term in the first line and not only the indented lines? Just give me a direction, I’ll work on it :)

Comment: @Sughanth I have added some details about the pattern to make it more clear how it works in parts. Currently, the 2 terms are looked for after first matching all the lines that start with `-`. If the terms can also be in the lines that start directly with `-`, the lookaheads should test all lines, regardless of indenting.